# Como identificar un archivo de un campo blob PHP y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenos dias mi pregunta es y que me ha estado atormentado

La cosa esta asi que tengo una base de datos donde subo un documentoPDF y pues me lo muestra con el iframe pero ya ahora que guardo tanto pdf como imagen jpg no me abre me da error, asi que queria saber si habra alguna manera de abrir los dos en el mismo iframe o tengo que hacer una condicion, pero el detalle que no se como hacerlo ya que si llega ser PDF se debe de abrir en el iframe y si llega ser imagen se deberia de abrir en el embed.

Dejo el codigo para saber como seria por favor por que no tengo forma de como identificar si es pdf o imagen.

```html
if(base64_encode($certificate) == 'application/pdf'){
  <?php
  <iframe  style="border:none;" src="<?php echo 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($certificate) ?>" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
  ?>
}
else {
  <?php
  <embed src="<?php echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($certificate) ?>" type="image/jpeg" width="100%" height="600px" />
  ?>
}
```

Comment: Te falla en ambos casos? Quitando la comparación te entra como pdf? Puedes utilizar var_dump($certificate) para ver que tiene dentro exactamente

Comment: Hola buenos dias y si se guarda como un archivo pdf si lo consulto de la bd y luego lo paso al iframe me muestra sin problemas el documentos pdf pero ahora el detalle esta que tambien guardo imagenes y si lo muestra con embed pero quisiera que con una condicion al momento de abrir el archivo si es pdf me lo muestre con iframe y si llega ser imagen con embed pero me muestra los dos iframe yembed juntos y si es imagen el del iframe donde muestro pdf igual se muestra en pantalla y no queiro eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay una forma 100% segura de saber de qué extensión es un `BLOB` leyendo el contenido mismo. A veces se guarda indicando el tipo entre los primeros caracteres del contenido, pero confiar en una solución basada en esa posibilidad sería un azar, aparte de que sería un manejo costoso, porque tendrías que leer el contenido del `BLOB`, extraerlo, manejarlo, tratar de buscar esos primeros caracteres para tratar de adivinar si es `PDF, JPG, JPEG, GIF`, etc.

La mejor solución es determinar el `MIME TYPE` al momento de guardar el `BLOB` y guardar esa información en una columna de la tabla. Eso te evitará hacer un `if` para saber de qué tipo es el archivo, pues recuperarías el  BLOB junto con el `MIME TYPE` y pondrías un header adecuado usando la información que haya en el `MIME TYPE`, sea cual sea.

Hay otras ventajas, por ejemplo, en el caso de que interese obtener solamente archivos de un determinado tipo, filtrarías con un `WHERE` para que te traiga solamente los archivos de ese tipo. O, imaginemos que en tu contexto se necesite un informe sobre cuántos archivos del tipo `X` existen ¿te imaginas tener que leer todos los contenidos `BLOB` para luego tratar de adivinar ahí dentro si existe algo como `PDF, JPG`, etc? Todo eso se simplifica con una columna que te indique el tipo de archivo.

[Aquí hay un tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/) bastante interesante para este tipo de manejos. Si implementas una clase te va a simplificar el trabajo.

Para determinar el `MIME TYPE` puedes usar [`mime_content_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php), o bien [`finfo_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.finfo-file.php).

Si no puedes modificar la tabla, puedes crear una nueva que guarde esa relación: el ID del archivo que se acaba de crear y la columna del mime type y obtener esa info uniendo las tablas mediante `JOIN`.

Es la mejor opción para tu caso.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tus comentarios de ayuda y si lo leere para resolver mi situacion. Gracias mi hermano.

Comment: @Pedro me alegro de que te haya servido. Si tienes problemas en algún otro punto de la implementación no dudes en plantearlo en Stackoverflow en una nueva pregunta. Saludos.